# Apache Superset Upgrade to 3.0.1 not initialising

Tags: apache-superset

I just upgraded by Apache superset to v3.0.1 and all dependency did went well with a successful installation. Though I followed the steps and the portal is even coming up, but my login is not working and keeps throwing random error.
Once it worked someone but then database connections were missing in UI, on adding it gave me error saying it already exist.

It is really troubling now and I don't have a clue what should be done next to make it working!

- ***I tried below***

`superset db upgrade`

```
`Loaded your LOCAL configuration at [/XXX/XXXX/XXX/myapplications/superset_config.py]
        logging was configured successfully
        2023-11-17 20:16:51,421:INFO:superset.utils.logging_configurator:logging was configured successfully
        2023-11-17 20:16:51,428:INFO:root:Configured event logger of type <class 'superset.utils.log.DBEventLogger'>
        /apps/XXX/XXXX/anaconda3/envs/superset_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_limiter/extension.py:336: UserWarning: Using the in-memory storage for tracking rate limits as no storage was explicitly specified. This is not recommended for production use. See: https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io#configuring-a-storage-backend for documentation about configuring the storage backend.
          warnings.warn(
        
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
```

Next I tried
`superset int` as well as `superset fab create-admin` but not much luck. Still could not login to portal.

[image: This gave]

Juts tried creating a new user as well, admin user

`superset fab create-admin`

[image]

[image]

Can see user is present in table as well but still not able to login on UI